# Github actions: automatic release action failed to find my artifacts

Tags: docker, github-actions, release

I'm trying to run the following workflow file:
https://github.com/ahmedmoselhi/pcsx2/blob/master/.github/workflows/release_pipeline.yml

but after I run the workflow I got the following error:

```
Error: /home/runner/work/pcsx2/pcsx2/ci-artifacts/* doesn't match any files
```

the job to create release and upload files:

```
  create_release:
    needs:
      - upload_artifacts
    name: "Create Release"
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ${{ github.WORKSPACE }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Prepare Artifact Folder
        run: mkdir -p ${{ github.WORKSPACE }}/ci-artifacts

      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        name: Download all Artifacts
        with:
          path: ${{ github.WORKSPACE }}/ci-artifacts
          
      - uses: "marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases@latest"
        name: Release
        with:
          repo_token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          automatic_release_tag: "latest"
          prerelease: true
          title: "Development Build"
          files: |
            ${{ github.WORKSPACE }}/ci-artifacts/*
```

Comment: Have you verified that the directory `${{ github.workspace }}/ci-artifacts/` indeed contains the downloaded artifacts e.g. with `ls` command in a separate step after downloading?

Comment: @Azzem yes I verified in previous step

Comment: Right. Do the downloaded artifacts exist?

Comment: yes all files there

Comment: Then, you can test by specifying the full name of some files to see whether it's working or not. You should also check the action repo to verify whether wildcards like that works or not. If you find issues with above then it's better to create an issue on the repo directly.